# Передача данных в другое окно JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Есть два окна. В первом окне есть `ComboBox`, куда выведен список, а также кнопка "Добавить", по нажатию на которую открывается второе окно, куда необходимо передать этот же список для `ComboBox` во втором окне и передать позицию выбранного элемента, чтобы также установить позицию во втором окне.

По нажатию на кнопку Добавить в первом окне происходят следующие действия:

```
public void onAdd(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    secondWindow.setList(comboList); //Передаем коллекцию для ComboBox во втором окне
    secondWindow.setSelectedIndex(comboTypePayer.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()); //Передаем индекс выбранного элемента
    ***
}
```

Во втором окне есть методы:

```
public void setList(ObservableList<String> list) {
    this.list = list;
    combobox.setItems(list);
}

public void setSelectedIndex(int i) {
    selectedIndex = i;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в каком методе мне необходимо вызвать строчку `combobox.getSelectionModel().select(selectedIndex);`, чтобы при открытии окно элемент уже был выбран?

Если вызывать эту строчку в методе `initialize` или setList возвращается `selectedIndex = 0` т.к. метод вызывается позже метода `initialize` или до метода `setList`

Comment: нужно обращаться к элементу по его ID

Comment: Как вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: где три звездочки

Comment: Можно пример? Не поняла о чем речь. Все элементы во втором окне у меня private. И ими управляю через открытые методы, которые во втором окне

Comment: Если у вас 2 FXML файла, и вы хотите чтобы между ними была связь, то вам нужен А) статическое "поле посредник" или Б)ссылка на контроллер, в который вы передаете информацию для определенного элемента, обращаясь к его ID. Вариант А самый простой, просто создайте публичную статическую переменную ТИП второго контроллера, и укажите джаве ссылку на эту переменную во время инициализации, используя слово this в контроллере №2.

Comment: Либо можно создать класс который будет хранить в себе ссылки на оба контроллера, и уже в нем обрабатывать всю инфу. По своему опыту скажу, что писать всё в контроллере плохо, поскольку это неминуемо ведет к спагетти коду

Comment: В данном случае мне нужно не столько получить управление компонентом из второго окна, а из первого передать список во вторую при открытии окна.

Comment: Тогда можно вынести сам компонент. Увы но в JFX контроллер инициализируется "сам" и по умолчанию он private объект. Т.Е просто так к его элементам не обратишься, у вас где-то должна быть ссылка.

Comment: Поняла. Попробую еще покопаться. Спасибо.